# Interpreting $\nabla {g}$ when $g(u,x,y)=0$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Say I have $u=f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Then $u-x^2-y^2=0$. We can write $g(u,x,y)=u-x^2-y^2=0$.

As a result, we have $\nabla {g}=(1,-2x,-2y)$.

How do we interpret $\nabla {g}$. If we were to plot $g$ for various values of $x$ and $y$, we'd get $0$ everywhere. But $\nabla {g}$, which could be interpreted as the rate of change of $g$ is non-zero at many points. For example, $g(2,1,1)=0$. Here, $\nabla {g}=(1,-2,-2)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the triple $(1,-2,-2)$ gives you the direction that standing at $(2,1,1)$ the function $f$ grows faster

Comment: How can something that is $0$ for all values of $x$ and $y$ grow?

Comment: $0$ is only the level of the paraboloid $u-x^2-y^2=0$

Comment: I feel this case is slightly different from a general level surface. If I say $u-x^2-y^2=0$, then I have to determine the values of $u,x,y$ such that this relation is defined. Here, there **cannot** be any values of $x,y,z$ such that $u-x^2-y^2\neq 0$. Hence, $f(u,x,y)=u-x^2-y^2$ is equal to $0$ for all $u,x,y$. In other words, I'm not trying to draw a level surface. A level surface is all that I'm getting.

Comment: anyway along this paraboloid the gradient $[1,-2x,-2y]$ gives you the direction at the position $(u,x,y)$ which $f$ varies more

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing yourself with poor notation.

If you have $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$, this defines a real valued function defined everywhere. It takes values in $[0,\infty)$.

If you pick some $u \in [0,\infty)$, and consider the set of $(x,y)$ pairs that satisfy the equation $f(x,y) = u$, that is, $L_u = \{ (x,y) | f(x,y) = u \}$ then you are no longer considering arbitrary pairs of $(x,y)$ pairs, but only considering those that satisfy the equation $f(x,y) = u$.

By reusing $f$ as in $f(u,x,y) = 0$ you are confusing things and the notation police will show up at your door. Let us use $\phi(u,x,y) =u-f(x,y)$ instead.

Now note that $\phi(u,x,y) = 0 $ **iff** $(x,y) \in L_u$. This does not mean that $\phi$ is zero everywhere. For example, if $\phi(u,x,y) = 0$, then we have $\phi(u+1,x,y) = 1$. The equation $\phi(u,x,y) = 0$ defines a surface $G \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ (in fact, it is the graph of the function $f$).

If you pick a point $(u',x',y') \in G$, then $\nabla \phi(u',x',y')$ is a normal to the surface $G$ at the point $(u',x',y')$.

Comment: $u$ is not a constant. It is a function. It is $f(x,y)$.

Comment: For context: "we have the quasi-linear equation $a(x,y,u)u_x+b(x,y,u)u_y-c(x,y,u)=0$. We assume the possible solution in the form $u=u(x,y)$."

Comment: @copper.hat- Sorry I forgot to address you in the above comments.

Comment: Then I am truly confused. You use $f$ above once with two parameters $(x,y)$ and then with three $(u,x,y)$. If you say $u=f(x,y)$ and then write $f(u,x,y)$ then I don't understand what you are writing.

Comment: @copper.hat- Terribly sorry for that. I think I have meaningful notation down now. I'm too used to referring to every function as $f$.

Comment: Then you need to write $g(f(x,y),x,y) = 0$, which is a function of $(x,y)$? I am still missing something.

Comment: No you're not. $g(f(x,y),x,y)=g(u,x,y)=u-x^2-y^2$. Remember that $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Now we know that $g(u,x,y)$ is identically $0$ for all $x,y$. So how does a non-zero $\bigtriangledown g$ make sense?

Comment: This is a function of $(x,y)$ not $(u,x,y)$, so the gradient with respect to $(u,x,y)$ is a bit meaningless in this context.

Comment: The gradient of $g(u,x,y)$ is used extensively in my book. I'll quote the parts: "we have the quasi-linear equation $a(x,y,u)u_x+b(x,y,u)u_y−c(x,y,u)=0$. We assume the possible solution in the form $u=u(x,y)$. Then we have $g(u,x,y)\equiv u(x,y)-u=0$. Hence, $\bigtriangledown g=(g_x,g_y,g_u)=(u_x,u_y,-1)$. This gradient vector is normal to the solution surface. "

Comment: @copper.gat- $g(x,y,u)$ is just the function obtained by bringing $u,x,y$ to the left hand side. Obviously, it will be identically equal to $0$ for all $x,y$

Comment: I think there is some notational abuse here...

Comment: @AyushKhaitan, $g$ is identically zero, *when confined to the surface*. But it easily extends to the ambient space of all $(u,x,y)$. In this extended space, we consider measuring the gradient, where $g$ sees all the other level surfaces.

Comment: You can define a function $g(a,b,c) = a-(b^2+c^2)$. This is defined everywhere and has gradient $(1, -2b, -2c)$. Then you must have $g(f(x,y),x,y) = 0$, where $f$ is defined as above. This is a function of $(x,y)$. Given any $(x,y)$, you can compute the gradient of $g$ at $(f(x,y),x,y)$, and, in general, it will not be zero.

Comment: @BradyTrainor- I think in this cae, there can't be any other level surfaces. Let $u=x^2+y^2$. All we're graphing is $u-x^2-y^2$. Hence, we're graphing $(x^2+y^2)-(x^2+y^2)$.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan, consider the point $(u,x,y)=(2,1,1)$. This point *is* on your surface. But $(u,x,y)=(3,1,1)$ is *not* on your surface. For the latter point, we have $g(3,1,1)=3-1^2-1^2=1$, thus corresponding to another level set, $g^{-1}(1)=\{(u,x,y,z):g(u,x,y)=1\}$. Every $g^{-1}(c)$ is *another* level set.

Answer (score 1):

You start with the $(x,y)$-plane and there have a function $f(x,y):=x^2+y^2$. Then you look at the graph 
$$G_f:=\{(x,y,u)\>|\> (x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2, \ u=f(x,y)\}$$ of this function, which is a surface in three-dimensional $(x,y,u)$-space. This surface can be viewed as solution set of the equation $u-x^2-y^2=0$. The left hand side
$g(x,y,u):= x^2+y^2-u$ of this equation is a function of three variables, and our graph $G_f$ is a **level surface** of this function $g$. It follows that at each point $(x,y,u)\in G_f$ the gradient $\nabla g(x,y,u)=(-2x,-2y,1)$ is orthogonal to the tangent plane of $G_f$ at $(x,y,u)$. If we project this gradient onto the $(x,y)$-plane we obtain $\nabla'g=(-2x,-2y)=-\nabla f(x,y)$. The latter "plane" gradient vector is at each point $(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2$ orthogonal to the **level line** of $f$ through $(x,y)$.